# Feature updating - add/replace files

Tags: sharepoint

I need to add/replace some files (ASPX, JS) in SPFeature on SharePoint 2013 Server. Could it be done via SPSolution update process? Is it possible to manage installed feature's files and WSP package's files in FeatureUpgrading event receiver?

Comment: The answer is yes, but the how depends on how and where you deployed your files (under 15 or with a module)

Comment: I place them in a "...\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\..." folder, so it's the first option I suppose...

Comment: when you update your solution (`Update-SPSolution`, I mean) files will be updated, and will reflect your package definition. Removed files from your package will also be deleted from the hard drive.

Comment: Removed files will NOT be deleted from the 15 hive when use Upgrade-SPSolution. You need to retract, delete, add and install the SPSolution, that's the best way. It will put the latest version in the corresponding 15-hive folder.

Comment: What if I have SPList deployed with Feature. I don't want to loose Items in this list, so I'm using FeatureUpgrading event receiver to do changes to list's schema. And I also need to manage aspx and js files...